# photoshop mockup for a section of a Joomla component

Tags: joomla, menu, photoshop

first post.

I have a joomla website with a webshop component called eshop
this eshop where you can filter categories looks like an unstiled list.

So I made a photoshop mockup of what I want it to look like. Now, with your help I can probably get that part done.

However, next thing is how do I implement it? should I use the rereplader, sourcerer components or should I go directly into the css file that governs the layout.

You see, this is pretty much way beyond my current skills so I really need help.

[What it currently looks like](http://blomist.se/shop/band/satinband)
[my photoshop mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTUQ6.png)

I used firebug in firefox to copy what I think is the HTML syntax and have started to css style it in dreamweaver but I'm stuck.

My current code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.eshop-sub-categories-list ul {
 width:736px;
 list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.eshop-sub-categories-list ul li { 
 display: inline-block;
 background: #eeeeee;
 margin-top:0px;
 margin-right:7px;
 margin-left:0px;
 margin-bottom: 7px;
 padding:0px;
  line-height:41px;
} 
.eshop-sub-categories-list .row-fluid a {
    color: #292828;
 text-decoration:none;
 width:137px;
 height:41px;
    display: block;
 text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="eshop-sub-categories-list"><div class="row-fluid">
   <h4>Refine Search</h4>
     <ul>
       <li>
     <h5>
      <a href="/blomist/shop/band/satinband/3mm-satinband">
       3mm Satinband      </a>
     </h5>
    </li>
        <li>
     <h5>
      <a href="/blomist/shop/band/satinband/6mm-satinband">
       6mm satinband      </a>
     </h5>
    </li>
        <li>
     <h5>
      <a href="/blomist/shop/band/satinband/10mm-satinband">
       10mm satinband      </a>
     </h5>
    </li>
        <li>
     <h5>
      <a href="/blomist/shop/band/satinband/12mm-satinband">
       12mm satinband      </a>
     </h5>
    </li>
        <li>
     <h5>
      <a href="/blomist/shop/band/satinband/25mm-satinband">
       25mm satinband      </a>
     </h5>
    </li>
        <li>
     <h5>
      <a href="/blomist/shop/band/satinband/30mm-satinband">
       30mm satinband      </a>
     </h5>
    </li>
        <li>
     <h5>
      <a href="/blomist/shop/band/satinband/38mm-satinband">
       38mm satinband      </a>
     </h5>
    </li>
        <li>
     <h5>
      <a href="/blomist/shop/band/satinband/50mm-satinband">
       50mm satinband      </a>
     </h5>
    </li>
        <li>
     <h5>
      <a href="/blomist/shop/band/satinband/100mm-satinband">
                              100mm satinband      </a>
     </h5>
    </li>
        <li>
     <h5>
      <a href="/blomist/shop/band/satinband/150mm-satinband">
       150mm satinband      </a>
     </h5>
    </li>
     
     </ul>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, don't override any core code.  If you do and a patch is released for the component, it will override your changes.

If Eshop allows you to add CSS in their admin configuration, do it there.

If not, and you have a bespoke template that is not going to be patched, it would be fine to add it there, though a better approach would be to use overrides - see [here](https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides) for how to do that.  Overrides would mean the additional CSS would only be loaded on the pages where the component appears, which keeps the code tidier.

I personally wouldn't use Sourcerer for anything, as that appears to encourage ignoring the Joomla framework, making a really messy codebase that may eventually become unmanageable.